# For loop to evaluate accuracy doesn't execute

Tags: python, numpy

So I've the following numpy arrays.

- X validation set, X_val: (47151, 32, 32, 1)
- y validation set (labels), y_val_dummy: (47151, 5, 10)
- y validation prediction set, y_pred: (47151, 5, 10)

When I run the code, it seems to take forever. Can someone suggest why? I  believe it's a code efficiency problem. I can't seem to complete the process.

```
y_pred_list = model.predict(X_val)
correct_preds = 0
# Iterate over sample dimension
for i in range(X_val.shape[0]):         
    pred_list_i = [y_pred_array[i] for y_pred in y_pred_array]
    val_list_i  = [y_val_dummy[i] for y_val in y_val_dummy]
    matching_preds = [pred.argmax(-1) == val.argmax(-1) for pred, val in zip(pred_list_i, val_list_i)]
    correct_preds = int(np.all(matching_preds))

total_acc = correct_preds / float(x_val.shape[0])
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[y_pred[i] for y_pred in y_pred_array]` instead and similarly for the next step?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks yeah. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

You're main problem is that you're generating a massive number of very large lists for no real reason

```
for i in range(X_val.shape[0]):
    # this line generates a 47151 x 5 x 10 array every time          
    pred_list_i = [y_pred_array[i] for y_pred in y_pred_array]
```

What's happening is that iterating over an nd numpy array iterates over the slowest varying index (i.e. the leftmost), so every list comprehension is running operating on 47K entries.

Marginally better would be

```
for i in range(X_val.shape[0]):         
    pred_list_i = [y_pred for y_pred in y_pred_array[i]]
    val_list_i  = [y_val for y_val in y_val_dummy[i]]
    matching_preds = [pred.argmax(-1) == val.argmax(-1) for pred, val in zip(pred_list_i, val_list_i)]
    correct_preds = int(np.all(matching_preds))
```

But you're still copying a lot of arrays for no real purpose. The following code should do the same, without the useless copying.

```
correct_preds = 0.0
for pred, val in zip(y_pred_array, y_val_dummy):
    correct_preds += all(p.argmax(-1) == v.argmax(-1) 
                         for p, v in zip(pred, val))
total_accuracy = correct_preds / x_val.shape[0]
```

This assumes that your criteria for a correct prediction is accurate.
You can probably avoid the explicit loop entirely with a couple of calls to `np.argmax`, but you'll have to work that out on your own.